# Android use Ksoap as an AsyncTask with parse variables and get returned values

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to use `AsyncTask` for Ksoap as an Thread.because my app don't work in Android 3 or above and that not any problem in Android 2. I want to develop this below code to send parameters to AsyncTask class and get values from that.

```
public class ReceivedSMS extends ListFragment implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

    public List<ReceiveFields> rows;

    private int prevVisibleItem;

    private TSMS tsms;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    public Long getLastID;

    private boolean isFirstTime;

    private Context context;

    private DatabaseHandler db;

    private SQLiteDatabase dbHelper;

    private ViewReceivedSMSDetailes receiveListView;


    public ReceivedSMS(Context context, String username, String password) {

        this.username = username;

        this.password = password;

        this.context = context;

    }

    public ReceivedSMS(String username, String password, long start, long count, Context context) {

        this.username = username;

        this.password = password;

        this.context = context;

        tsms = new TSMS(context, new User(this.username, this.password));

        try {

            getReceivedSMS(start, count);

        } catch (Exception e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();

            Log.e("Error in getReceivedSMS(start, count); ", "");
        }

    }

    public List<ReceiveFields> getReceivedSMS(long start, long count) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        tsms = new TSMS(context, new User(this.username, this.password));

        try {

            rows = tsms.getReceivedSMS(start, count);

            saveRowsintoDatabase( rows );

        } catch (TException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            Log.e(getClass().toString(), "ERROR IN Fetch SMS From WebService List<ReceiveFields> getReceivedSMS(long start, long count) "+ String.valueOf(e));

        }

        return rows;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        db = new DatabaseHandler(context);

        dbHelper = db.getWritableDatabase();

        setReceivedSMSToListView();

    }

}

private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    }

}
```

this code is not problem but i want to move action from constructors to `AsyncCallWS` such as :

1) in this constructor:

```
public ReceivedSMS(String username, String password, long start, long count, Context context) {

    this.username = username;

    this.password = password;

    this.context = context;

    tsms = new TSMS(context, new User(this.username, this.password));

    try {

        getReceivedSMS(start, count);

    } catch (Exception e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();

        Log.e("Error in getReceivedSMS(start, count); ", "");
    }

}
```

i want to move:

```
tsms = new TSMS(context, new User(this.username, this.password));

        try {

            getReceivedSMS(start, count);

        } catch (Exception e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();

            Log.e("Error in getReceivedSMS(start, count); ", "");
        }
```

to `AsyncCallWS` class and this constructor:

```
public List<ReceiveFields> getReceivedSMS(long start, long count) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    tsms = new TSMS(context, new User(this.username, this.password));

    try {

        rows = tsms.getReceivedSMS(start, count);

        saveRowsintoDatabase( rows );

    } catch (TException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        Log.e(getClass().toString(), "ERROR IN Fetch SMS From WebService "+ String.valueOf(e));

    }

    return rows;
}
```

can be get `rows` from `AsyncCallWS` class. `AsyncCallWS` class.

**UPDATE POST:**

in this class `doInBackground` function do not allow to return String

```
public class WSDLHelper {
    public static String call(SoapObject request){
        ProcessTask p =new ProcessTask(request);
        return p.execute();
    }
}
class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, SoapObject > {
    SoapObject request;

    public String ProcessTask(SoapObject rq){

        request = rq;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String result = null;

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        AndroidHttpTransport transport = new AndroidHttpTransport(Strings.URL_TSMS);
        transport.debug = true;

        try {
            transport.call(Strings.URL_TSMS + request.getName(), envelope);
            result = envelope.getResponse().toString();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e("" , ex.getMessage());
        } catch (XmlPullParserException ex) {
            Log.e("" , ex.getMessage());
        }

        if (result.equals(String.valueOf(Integers.CODE_USER_PASS_FALSE)))
             return result;
        else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Dhruti i can not move actions from constructor to `AsyncCallWS` class and get values from that.

Comment: If you want to return String then change `class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, SoapObject >` to `class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String >`.

Comment: Concerning the "UPDATE POST", which is based on Dhruti's wrong proposal to call *String result = p.execute();*, please refer to the answered follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758236/android-asynctask-dont-return-correct-result/25865438

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) first.

```
public class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>{
    String s1, s2, s3, s4;

    public ProcessTask(String str1, String str2, String str3, String str4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        s1 = str1;
        s2 = str2;
        s3 = str3;
        s4 = str4;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //do something with strings
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //your code of parsing

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Call it as:

```
ProcessTask p = new ProcessTask(s1, s2, s3, s4);
p.execute();
```

Hope this helps.

To return a `List<ReceiveFields>`, change:

```
public class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>
```

to

```
public class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, List<ReceiveFields>>
```

You would need to remove existing overriden method which returns String and override the proper method doInBackground, which returns List.

Comment: thanks my `doInBackground` must be returned `ReceiveFields` but that dont allow it to change from `protected String doInBackground` to `protected List<ReceiveFields> doInBackground`

Comment: can you help me to Updated Post?

Comment: @MahdiPishguy for returning string use `class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String >`.