# Android AsyncTask don't return correct Result

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-ksoap2

for one of projects i want to use `Ksoap` with `AsyncTask`. now in this below code `AsyncTask` can work correctly but after return result to `WSDLHeper` i get wronge value. for example Result for `this.result` in `doInBackground` method is :

```
[1, 4674070, {item=3000738; item=TSMS; item=30007227; item=30004444440000; item=30007227001401; item=50004066569100; item=50001717; item=500017171; item=5000171717; item=50001717007227; }]
```

after return value i'm in `tmp = String.valueOf(p.execute())` have :

```
ir.tsms.wsdl.ProcessTask@417b65e0
```

in this line:

```
tmp = String.valueOf(p.execute());
```

and thats wronge `tmp` must be have

```
[1, 4674070, {item=3000738; item=TSMS; item=30007227; item=30004444440000; item=30007227001401; item=50004066569100; item=50001717; item=500017171; item=5000171717; item=50001717007227; }]
```

to return.

My code:

```
public class WSDLHelper {
    public SoapObject request;
    public static String call(SoapObject rq){

        String tmp;
        ProcessTask p =new ProcessTask(rq);

        tmp = String.valueOf(p.execute());

        return tmp;
    }

}
class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String > {
    SoapObject req1;
    private String result;
    public ProcessTask(SoapObject rq) {
        req1 = rq;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(this.req1);

        AndroidHttpTransport transport = new AndroidHttpTransport(Strings.URL_TSMS);
        transport.debug = true;

        try {
            transport.call(Strings.URL_TSMS + this.req1.getName(), envelope);
            this.result = envelope.getResponse().toString();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e("" , ex.getMessage());
        } catch (XmlPullParserException ex) {
            Log.e("" , ex.getMessage());
        }

        if (result.equals(String.valueOf(Integers.CODE_USER_PASS_FALSE))) {
            try {
                throw new TException(PublicErrorList.USERNAME_PASSWORD_ERROR);
            } catch (TException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
        return this.result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to get right value of tmp , try to get this value in  onPostExecute() method.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot get the return value of AsyncTask by

`tmp = String.valueOf(p.execute());`

This is because Android app doesn't wait for AsyncTask to return a value to move to next line.

You need to use the `onPostExecute()` Method to process the return value of an AsyncTask .

You can refer [AsyncTask: where does the return value of doInBackground() go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489399/asynctask-where-return-value-of-doinbackground-goes)  for more syntax and more information.

Comment: `onPostExecute()` is `void` by default and i can not use `return this.result` into that. please help me to return value from it to `WSDLHelper` Thanks. your introducing link  `onPostExecute()` don't return any value

Comment: Protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
          showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
      } I understand your concern that this doesn't return anything. But you get the return value of doInBackground() as a parameter of onPostExecute().  For example ,  if you need to return String from the doInBackground() method, then use onPostExecute(String)

Answer (score 2):

you can't return value from asyncTask at all, you can parse result, do what ever you want inside `doInbackground()` or in `onPostExecute()`, if you want more flexibility, you can call a method exist out of the asyncTask passing the result from `onPostexecute()`:

```
private void continueWithResult(String data){
//do whatever you want with the json passed from onPostExecute()
}

class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String > {
:
:
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        continueWithResult(result);
    }
:
:
```

and you really need to read the link posted by JTsunami

Answer (score 1):

It seems this question spawned from Mahdi's confusion with [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25718517/2964379), which formerly suggested using

```
ProcessTask p = new ProcessTask(...);
String result = p.execute();
```

This obviously can't work as explained by JTsunami here. Anyway, because of that confusion, the intention of Mahdi here is to create and execute the AsyncTask (asynchronously!) and then return the result of the AsyncTask (synchronously!) when it hasn't received the result yet. The only solution is to **handle the result INSIDE onPostExecute()**. If you need to pass the result to other objects, like an Activity or Fragment, you have to **actively pass the result because execute() and call(...) will never wait for it**. A good option is to register a listener by replacing

```
public static String call(SoapObject request) {
    ProcessTask p =new ProcessTask(request);
    return p.execute();
}

class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, SoapObject>
    SoapObject request;

    public String ProcessTask(SoapObject rq) {
        request = rq;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

with

```
public void String call(SoapObject request, ResultListener listener) {
    ProcessTask p = new ProcessTask(request, listener);
    p.execute();
}

class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, SoapObject>
    private SoapObject request;
    private ResultListener listener;

    public String ProcessTask(SoapObject rq, ResultListener l) {
        request = rq;
        listener = l;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        listener.onResult(result);
    }
}

public interface ResultListener {
    void onResult(String result);
}
```

Now you would call

```
WSDLHelper.call(-your SoapObject here-, new ResultListener() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(String result) {
        // do whatever you want with the result
    }
});
```

which will make sure you **receive the result asynchronously, but still in the same class that calls the method**. Note that the return type of call(...) is void: **You have to handle the result inside onResult()**.